# GTK3 program no longer compiles - GCC "undefined reference" at link time

Tags: gcc, reference, undefined, gtk3

So I was merrily learning GTK+ programming with 3.0 in Ubuntu 11.04, and even got a working ruler program running.  It compiled with my makefile perfectly.

I took some time away from it, upgraded to 11.10, and now have come back to it.  But, alas, when I try to build the program, I get a lot of "undefined reference" errors to pretty much every gtk call in my program.  Compiling is fine - the issue is at link time.

The project can be found here:  https://github.com/zjmichen/ruler

Comment: External link to problem is no longer valid, so question is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested it and it compiled fine.

```
superman@superman-mint ~/work/zjmichen-ruler-e783fe1 $ make
gcc -c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` main.c
gcc -c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` window.c
gcc -c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` graphics.c
gcc -c -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` mouse.c
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` main.o window.o graphics.o mouse.o -o zruler
superman@superman-mint ~/work/zjmichen-ruler-e783fe1 $
```

But this was on Linux Mint. Here you've got the arguments produced by pkg-config

```
-pthread -DGSEAL_ENABLE -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pixman-1  -pthread -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0
```

I've also did a quick test on Ubuntu 11.10 and indeed it doesn't compile. I'll take a better look this evening.

So I did test it on Ubuntu and changed the line 14 in the makefile to

```
$(CC) $(OBJS) $(GTKFLAGS) -o $(NAME)
```

this changes the order of object files and libraries that are being linked. I have no idea why this problem occurs on the new Ubuntu. Maybe it is because it is a different version of gcc. On my linux mint gcc is version 4.5.2 on ubuntu 11.10 it is 4.6.1

Comment: Why are you feeding the --libs output from pkg-config to the compilation and the --cflags to the linking phase? This is not good style and educational

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I currently don't have access to a running Linux machine with GTK3.0 installed, but looking at your code I noticed the inclusion of X11/xlib.h in main.c. Since you are not using X11 code anywhere in your code and you are using 'pkgconfig ... gtk+-3.0' instead of gtk+-X11-3.0, I assume you could remove that include statement. If you do need the X11 libraries the make sure it is listed in the compiler flags. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check it out - the reason I include X11 (at least in window.c) is to find the cursor position, even when it isn't in the window.  I couldn't find Gtk functionality for this, but if you know a better way to do that, I would be grateful.  Of course, that's a different issue.

Anyway, the problem persists despite removing this dependency.